# C# Массив строк в массив объектов определенного типа

Tags: c#

Есть заполненный массив строк

```
string[] s;
```

Есть заполненный массив типов

```
Type[] types;
```

Нужно конвертировать массив строк в массив объектов object[] obj где каждая строка s[i] конвертируется в объект типа types[i].

Это нужно для вызова

```
mi.Invoke(this, obj);
```

Пример

```
public enum CountType
{
    First,
    Second
}
string[] s=new string[] {"Vasya","1.2","Second"};
Type[] types=new Type[]{typeof(string),typeof(double),typeof(CountType)};
```

Comment: "ковертировать" - ??

Comment: Есть массив кошек. Надо его конвертировать в массив звездолетов. Как это сделать?

Comment: @tym32167 очень хорошо, что Вы спросили. Клизма из скипидара.

Comment: думаю тут у каждого типа через `reflection` находить статический метод который преобразовывает строку в нужный тип

Comment: @dgzargo но мы же ничего не знаем про строки. Как вы предполагаете сконвертировать произвольную строку во что либо?

Comment: @tym32167 Кто сказал что не знаем? Я же четко написал что для каждой строки известен ее тип который хранится в types.

Comment: @jshapen у любой строки тип String, примеры строк и типов вы не показали, примеры что и во что конвертировать вы не показали, я вам собственно на это и пытаюсь намекать

Comment: например, у меня есть строка "Вася" и тип Double - что мне с ними делать? Что и во что конвертировать?

Comment: ну и, что это `mi.Invoke(this, obj);` и как оно относится к задаче совсем не ясно

Comment: попробуйте прочитать ваш вопрос глазами человека, который не в курсе, что вы делаете и зачем, и поймете о чем я говорю - у вас в вопросе мало деталей. Рекомендую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tym32167 Строки всегда соответствуют типу. Если "Вася" то String. Дополню вопрос примером...

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил пример

Comment: А зачем вам вообще такие сложности? Почему сразу не писать массив с нужными типами? Получите что то вроде `object[] s=new object[] { "Vasya", 1.2, CountType.Second };`. Странный у вас конечно подход...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Конечно, я бы так и сделал, но на момент компиляции ничего не известно о типах и строках. Они приходят извне.

Comment: ну у вас хотя бы есть список возможных типов? Или там может быть любой тип? Например, я свой класс напишу, `MyClass`  - он может быть в этом списке?

Comment: Любой тип может быть

Comment: тогда вы никак не решите задачу. Я, например, могу написать класс, который легко конвертируется в строку, но никогда не конвертируется из строки в класс.

Comment: @tym32167 Будем считать что используются только все стандартные типы и всевозможные Enum'ы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс [`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2) реализует интерфейс [`IConvertible`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netframework-4.7.2), это означает, что объект этого типа можно конвертировать в стандартные типы `bool`, `double` и т.д.

Для преобразования можно воспользоваться методом [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_).

Однако, это не поможет с `Enum`.

Если нужный тип `enum` - нужно воспользоваться методом [`Enum.Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_Parse_System_Type_System_String_)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, у нас есть конвертеры типов

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<String, object>> _converters =
    new Dictionary<System.Type, System.Func<string, object>>()
    {
        { typeof(int), (str)=>int.Parse(str) },
        { typeof(double), (str)=>double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
        { typeof(CountType), (str)=>Enum.Parse(typeof(CountType), str) },
        { typeof(string), (str)=>str }, 
    };
```

Тогда конвертация 1 элемента будет выглядеть вот так:

```
object Convert(string str, Type type)
{
    if (_converters.ContainsKey(type)) return _converters[type](str);
    return null;
}
```

Конвертация массива

```
object[] Convert(string[] strings, Type[] types)
{
    var ret = new object[strings.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        ret[i] = Convert(strings[i], types[i]);
    return ret; 
}
```

Как использовать:

```
string[] s = new string[] { "Vasya", "1.2", "Second" };
Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(double), typeof(CountType) };

foreach(var item in Convert(s, types))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.GetType().Name} {item}");
}
```

Comment: если убрать из `_converters` enum - то описана работа `Convert.ChangeType` :-)

Comment: @Grundy ну я не сильно заморачивался, хотел просто принцип показать

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант...

```
var result = s.Zip(types, (st, t) => new { Value = st, Type = t }).Select(x =>
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(x.Type);
    return converter.ConvertFrom(x.Value);
});
```

Только тут стоит сделать пару дополнений, например в приведенных вами данных тип double скорей всего выдаст ошибку, ибо в нашей культуре принято разделять через запятую значения, а не через точку.